# How is まま used here?

Tags: grammar

From [here](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%8F%8D%E9%81%93%E4%B8%AD)

珍道中
読み方：ちんどうちゅう

めずらしい旅。旅の途中で珍奇な出来事に**まま**遭遇するような旅のこと。

What does まま modify here, what clause(word?) is it part of?

Comment: 多分これです。普通は「ままある」の形でしか使わないんですが。 https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%96%93%E9%96%93-635665#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @marasai in the comment, 「まま」, in this context, is an adverb meaning "***once in a while***".  One could say it is synonymous to 「ときどき」、「[時]{とき}として」, etc.

Since it is an adverb, it modifies the following verb 「[遭遇]{そうぐう}する」(= to encounter).

This 「まま」 and the particle 「まま」(as in 「[立]{た}った**まま**[食]{た}べる」) are two different words and they are pronounced differently.

Adverb: 「まま{HL}」

Particle: 「まま{LH}」

Not to sound irrelevant: 「ママ{HL}」

Comment: +1, but I personally say like [まま]{LH} even when it's an adverb. (it's a rare adverb and I may be wrong)